# sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:driver

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, alembic

I am trying to run `alembic` migration and when I run

```
alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Added initial tables"
```

It fails saying

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:driver
```

the database url is

```
postgresql+psycopg2://dev:passwd@localhost/db
```

and I even have `psycopg2` installed in my virtualenv

```
$yolk -l
Flask-Login     - 0.1.3        - active
Flask-SQLAlchemy - 0.16         - active
Flask           - 0.9          - active
Jinja2          - 2.6          - active
Mako            - 0.7.3        - active
MarkupSafe      - 0.15         - active
Python          - 2.7.2        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload)
SQLAlchemy      - 0.8.0        - active
Werkzeug        - 0.8.3        - active
alembic         - 0.4.2        - active
antiorm         - 1.1.1        - active
appscript       - 1.0.1        - active
distribute      - 0.6.27       - active
envoy           - 0.0.2        - active
osascript       - 0.0.4        - active
pep8            - 1.4.5        - active
pip             - 1.1          - active
psycopg2        - 2.4.6        - active
wsgiref         - 0.1.2        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7)
yolk            - 0.4.3        - active
```

Whay could be causing this issue?

Comment: change driver:// to mysql:// or sqlite:// on sqlalchemy.url

Comment: I found that the error included "sqlalchemy.dialects:driver" when the alembic.ini / sqlalchemy.url started with "driver:// ...", instead of an actual driver name like "postgresql".

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Here's how to produce an error like that:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import *
>>> create_engine("driver://")
Traceback (most recent call last):
... etc
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:driver
```

so I'd say you aren't actually using the postgresql URL you think you are - you probably are calling upon a default-generated alembic.ini somewhere.

Comment: You are right, I was messing up somewhere(not sure exactly where), I am able to move the process forward, although held up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660676/alembic-autogenerate-producing-empty-migration, let me know if you have any ideas. THANK YOU very much for your help

Comment: Didn't notice that `alembic.ini` got created in the parent directory of the `alembic` directory. Thanks!

Comment: To set the db URL dynamically, see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27256675/9494790

Answer (score 21):

For those who haven't noticed it, the "default-generated alembic.ini" **zzzzeek** refers to is in the root directory of the project.

The whole problem is one of setting the `sqlalchemy.url` config parameter in the `alembic.ini` file. Also, it can be set programmatically as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15668175/973380.

Comment: the `alembic.ini` can be *anywhere*. And Mike's nick has only 3 `z`s :d

Answer (score 12):

Notice that the scheme doesn't actually specify the driver but the *dialect*: the scheme is of form `dialect://` *or* `dialect+driver://`.

For example the correct urls to connect to a PostgreSQL database would start with for example `postgresql://` (which defaults to using `psycopg2`), or choosing a driver explicitly (`postgresql+psycopg2://`, or with another driver).

If you happen to specify *only* `psycopg2` you will get the error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:psycopg2
```

Comment: For Airflow (Celery) users: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39967889/3299397

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks, I am not sure if it was ever right :'D

Answer (score 2):

To programmatically override the default value in `alembic.ini`, you can add a line or two of code in `alembic/env.py`:

```
+ import app

[...snip...]

  # this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
  # access to the values within the .ini file in use.
  config = context.config

+ config.set_section_option(
    config.config_ini_section, "sqlalchemy.url", app.settings.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL
)
```

where `import app` and `app.settings.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL` are replaced by your own application-specific code to retrieve the URL.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by simply opening the alembic.ini in notepad++ and then amending the variable sqlachemy.url (on about line 38) to the url in my project file. The error is most likely caused because it has driver at the beginning.

i.e. renaming this line to

```
sqlalchemy.url = sqlite:///name_of_my_database.db
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were following the correct syntax for creating an engine, depending on your database of choice, `create_engine(f"<dialect_name>+<driver_name>://{self.user}:{self.password}@{self.host}:{self.port}/{self.database})` and none of the other suggestions here fix your problem, you can try the solution outlined in the next paragraph.

The issue, `NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:\<dialect_name\>.\<driver_name\>`, can be caused by running an SQLAlchemy version that does support the driver you need. For example, SQLAlchemy 1.4.26 supports these PostgreSQL [drivers](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html). So, the solution:

1. Check the documentation for supported drivers, for the dialect you need.
2. Then uninstall SQLAlchemy or the problematic driver `pip uninstall SQLAlchemy`
3. Force pip to install specific version of SQLAlchemy or an alternative driver, `pip install SQLAlchemy==1.0.14`

Answer (score 1):

```
connection_url=""  
#your database connection string here pulled from either environment variable , vaults or can be set directly

def run_migrations_offline():
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = connection_url 
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    configdict=config.get_section(config.config_ini_section)
    configdict.update({"sqlalchemy.url":connection_url})
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        configdict,
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()
```

if you want to read the connection url from your python file itself without refering to default

> alembic.ini

config file.

Answer (score 0):

Try those commands to install missing packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev 
sudo pip install psycopg2 
sudo pip install redshift-sqlalchemy 
sudo pip install sqlparse
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the Teradata Queries to run on the .exe produced by Pyinstaller. I changed my engine from SQLAlchemy to Teradata

From :

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
user, pasw, hostname = UserName,Password, 'myurl.com'
# connect
td_engine = sa.create_engine('teradata://{}:{}@{}:22/'.format(user,pasw,hostname),echo=True)
df = pd.read_sql_query(query1,connect)
```

To:

```
import teradata
user, pasw, hostname = UserName,Password, 'myurl.com'
td = teradata.UdaExec (appName="test", version="1.0", logConsole=True)
td_engine = td.connect(method="odbc",system=hostname, username=user,password=pasw,driver="Teradata")
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, inside the file **alembic/env.py**
I mistakenly used

```py
config.get_main_option
```

instead of

```
config.set_main_option
```

PS:

```py
config = context.config
```

Answer (score -2):

I did,

```
pip install ibm_db_sa
```

it fixed problem

Answer (score -2):

uninstall anaconda if you have it. it is installing your mysql connector in the anaconda path and your code is probably looking in the python path.