# Migrate SQLAlchemy models having dates without timezone to ones with timezone

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

I have some SQLAlchemy models defined like this:

```py
class TimeData(object):
    __table_args__ = {"extend_existing": True}

    created_on = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=db.func.now())
    updated_on = Column(
        DateTime(timezone=True),
        server_default=db.func.now(),
        server_onupdate=db.func.now(),
        onupdate=db.func.now(),
    )


class Article(db.Model, TimeData):
    id = Column(db.Integar, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(db.Text)
    contents = Column(db.Text)
    last_reviewed_on = Column(db.DateTime)


class Review(db.Model, TimeData):
    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    review = Column(db.Text)
    rating = Column(db.Integer)
    read_on = Column(db.DateTime)
```

As one can see, the `DateTime` objects which are inherited from the `TimeData` class are marked with `timezone=True` while the dates defined in the models themselves are not. This results two different types of date strings when serializing.

The `created_on` gets serialized into something like `2019-11-25T01:53:05.576Z` with the Z in the end, while values like `read_on` get serialized into `2019-11-25T01:53:05.576` without the Z. Since we store everything in UTC, the date information in the DB is fine. But the serialized output is causing problems in the client side when the browser evaluated the dates. The ones with the Z are read as UTC, while the ones without Z are read as local time.

As a solution, migrating the models doesn't seem to work. When `timezone=True` is added to the models, Flask-Migrate (Alembic) doesn't detect any changes in the models.

How to migrate the dates to ones with TimeZone?

Comment: Have this exact same issue. Who knew going down this rabbit hole of adding a Z to the end of Python date string would go on forever :( Did you ever come up with a solution?

Comment: Nope. The code still runs with the hack of adding Z :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I ended up solving it with adding `timezone=True` to my datetime fields.

You are right that by default that change is not picked up by Flask-Migrate but after adding `compare_type=true` to your configuration in env.py it does.

```
    context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata,
            compare_type=True
            )
```

see for details: [Can Alembic Autogenerate column alterations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17176843/1256694)

After generating the migration and upgrading my db my datetime fields all returning UTC (with z at the end) in the output.