# Error while connecting postgres db from airflow

Tags: sqlalchemy, celery, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Using:

`sql_alchemy_conn = db+postgresql://username:xxx@127.0.0.1:5432/airflow`
gives error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:db.postgresql

and when using:

`sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://username:xxx@localhost:5432/airflow`
I could run the `airlfow webserver -p 8080` but while running the scheduler: `airflow scheduler` it throws error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
>   [image]

packages versions I am using:

```
psycopg2==2.7.3.1
sqlalchemy==1.1.15
sqlalchemy-redshift== 0.7.0
apache_airflow=1.8.2
```

Earlier `sql_alchemy_conn = db+postgresql://username:xxx@127.0.0.1:5432/airflow` did worked for me - 2 months ago. I don't know what is the problem now.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Include tracebacks as text, in their entirety. The (typical) form of DB URL is `dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database` and I'm pretty sure the dialect "db" has never existed. Typical values would be postgresql, mysql, mssql, and such.

Comment: Earlier I followed the answer posted here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785061/unable-to-start-airflow-worker-flower-and-need-clarification-on-airflow-architec  about using "db" and it worked then. Now it is causing problem because of the upgrades in some packages, I tried all possible solutions that I could found - nothing worked.

Comment: Ah it's a configuration URL for Celery, not SQLAlchemy, so that's why. They look rather similar, but are meant for different things, it'd seem. About that module not found, it'd seem Celery is for some reason trying to pass SQLAlchemy a DB URL that is using the MySQL dialect and MySQLdb driver specifically. A default perhaps?

Comment: This:`result_backend = 'db+postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/mydatabase'` is the celery format to connect postgres database as mentioned in official documentation:http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html, but this did not work either.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

finally,the following settings worked - in [airflow.cfg](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-config.html):

```
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://scot:tiger@localhost:5432/airflow
celery_result_backend = db+postgres://scot:tiger@localhost:5432/airflow
```

It is important to note that dialect+driver are different for `sql_alchemy_conn` and `celery_result_backend` settings in airflow.cfg file, although they are pointing to the same database.

Comment: I am doing it exactly like this, webserver & scheduler are running fine as well, but when I do `$ airflow celery worker`, I get `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "postgres" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`, I checked `airflow.cfg`, no where in there I wrongly have placed `postgres` in place of `localhost`.

Comment: should I put these in settings.py? or where?

Comment: You should put it in `airflow.cfg`

Comment: Also for me the Celery results backend is called just `result_backend` instead of `celery_result_backend`