# Airflow CeleryExecutor With AWS SQS

Tags: postgresql, celery, amazon-sqs, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm trying to cluster my Airflow setup and I'm using [this article](http://site.clairvoyantsoft.com/setting-apache-airflow-cluster/) to do so. I just configured my `airflow.cfg` file to use the `CeleryExecutor`, I pointed my `sql_alchemy_conn` to my postgresql database that's running on the same master node, I've set the `broker_url` to use SQS (I didn't set the access_key_id or secret_key since it's running on an EC2-Instance it doesn't need those), and I've set the `celery_result_backend` to my postgresql server too. I saved my new airflow.cfg changes, I ran `airflow initdb`, and then I ran `airflow scheduler` and I'm getting this error from the scheduler,

```
[2018-06-07 21:07:33,420] {celery_executor.py:101} ERROR - Error syncing the celery executor, ignoring it:
[2018-06-07 21:07:33,421] {celery_executor.py:102} ERROR - Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 83, in sync
    state = async.state
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 433, in state
    return self._get_task_meta()['status']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 372, in _get_task_meta
    return self._maybe_set_cache(self.backend.get_task_meta(self.id))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 344, in get_task_meta
    meta = self._get_task_meta_for(task_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/database/__init__.py", line 53, in _inner
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/database/__init__.py", line 122, in _get_task_meta_for
    session = self.ResultSession()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/database/__init__.py", line 99, in ResultSession
    **self.engine_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/database/session.py", line 59, in session_factory
    engine, session = self.create_session(dburi, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/database/session.py", line 45, in create_session
    engine = self.get_engine(dburi, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/database/session.py", line 42, in get_engine
    return create_engine(dburi, poolclass=NullPool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 424, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 57, in create
    entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 156, in _get_entrypoint
    cls = registry.load(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 221, in load
    (self.group, name))
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:psycopg2
```

Here is my `airflow.cfg` file,

```
[core]
# The home folder for airflow, default is ~/airflow
airflow_home = /home/ec2-user/airflow

# The folder where your airflow pipelines live, most likely a
# subfolder in a code repository
# This path must be absolute
dags_folder = /home/ec2-user/airflow/dags

# The folder where airflow should store its log files
# This path must be absolute
base_log_folder = /home/ec2-user/airflow/logs

# Airflow can store logs remotely in AWS S3 or Google Cloud Storage. Users
# must supply an Airflow connection id that provides access to the storage
# location.
remote_log_conn_id =
encrypt_s3_logs = False

# Logging level
logging_level = INFO

# Logging class
# Specify the class that will specify the logging configuration
# This class has to be on the python classpath
# logging_config_class = my.path.default_local_settings.LOGGING_CONFIG
logging_config_class =

# Log format
log_format = [%%(asctime)s] {%%(filename)s:%%(lineno)d} %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s
simple_log_format = %%(asctime)s %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s

# The executor class that airflow should use. Choices include
# SequentialExecutor, LocalExecutor, CeleryExecutor, DaskExecutor
#executor = SequentialExecutor
executor = CeleryExecutor

# The SqlAlchemy connection string to the metadata database.
# SqlAlchemy supports many different database engine, more information
# their website
#sql_alchemy_conn = sqlite:////home/ec2-user/airflow/airflow.db
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:$password@localhost/datalake_airflow_cluster_v1_master1_database_1

# The SqlAlchemy pool size is the maximum number of database connections
# in the pool.
sql_alchemy_pool_size = 5

# The SqlAlchemy pool recycle is the number of seconds a connection
# can be idle in the pool before it is invalidated. This config does
# not apply to sqlite.
sql_alchemy_pool_recycle = 3600

# The amount of parallelism as a setting to the executor. This defines
# the max number of task instances that should run simultaneously
# on this airflow installation
parallelism = 32

# The number of task instances allowed to run concurrently by the scheduler
dag_concurrency = 16

# Are DAGs paused by default at creation
dags_are_paused_at_creation = True

# When not using pools, tasks are run in the "default pool",
# whose size is guided by this config element
non_pooled_task_slot_count = 128

# The maximum number of active DAG runs per DAG
max_active_runs_per_dag = 16

# Whether to load the examples that ship with Airflow. It's good to
# get started, but you probably want to set this to False in a production
# environment
load_examples = True

# Where your Airflow plugins are stored
plugins_folder = /home/ec2-user/airflow/plugins

# Secret key to save connection passwords in the db
fernet_key = ibwZ5uSASmZGphBmwdJ4BIhd1-5WZXMTTgMF9u1_dGM=

# Whether to disable pickling dags
donot_pickle = False

# How long before timing out a python file import while filling the DagBag
dagbag_import_timeout = 30

# The class to use for running task instances in a subprocess
task_runner = BashTaskRunner

# If set, tasks without a `run_as_user` argument will be run with this user
# Can be used to de-elevate a sudo user running Airflow when executing tasks
default_impersonation =

# What security module to use (for example kerberos):
security =

# Turn unit test mode on (overwrites many configuration options with test
# values at runtime)
unit_test_mode = False

# Name of handler to read task instance logs.
# Default to use file task handler.
task_log_reader = file.task

# Whether to enable pickling for xcom (note that this is insecure and allows for
# RCE exploits). This will be deprecated in Airflow 2.0 (be forced to False).
enable_xcom_pickling = True

# When a task is killed forcefully, this is the amount of time in seconds that
# it has to cleanup after it is sent a SIGTERM, before it is SIGKILLED
killed_task_cleanup_time = 60

[cli]
# In what way should the cli access the API. The LocalClient will use the
# database directly, while the json_client will use the api running on the
# webserver
api_client = airflow.api.client.local_client
endpoint_url = http://localhost:8080

[api]
# How to authenticate users of the API
auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.default

[operators]
# The default owner assigned to each new operator, unless
# provided explicitly or passed via `default_args`
default_owner = Airflow
default_cpus = 1
default_ram = 512
default_disk = 512
default_gpus = 0


[webserver]
# The base url of your website as airflow cannot guess what domain or
# cname you are using. This is used in automated emails that
# airflow sends to point links to the right web server
base_url = http://localhost:8080

# The ip specified when starting the web server
web_server_host = 0.0.0.0

# The port on which to run the web server
web_server_port = 8080

# Paths to the SSL certificate and key for the web server. When both are
# provided SSL will be enabled. This does not change the web server port.
web_server_ssl_cert =
web_server_ssl_key =

# Number of seconds the gunicorn webserver waits before timing out on a worker
web_server_worker_timeout = 120

# Number of workers to refresh at a time. When set to 0, worker refresh is
# disabled. When nonzero, airflow periodically refreshes webserver workers by
# bringing up new ones and killing old ones.
worker_refresh_batch_size = 1

# Number of seconds to wait before refreshing a batch of workers.
worker_refresh_interval = 30

# Secret key used to run your flask app
secret_key = temporary_key

# Number of workers to run the Gunicorn web server
workers = 4

# The worker class gunicorn should use. Choices include
# sync (default), eventlet, gevent
worker_class = sync

# Log files for the gunicorn webserver. '-' means log to stderr.
access_logfile = -
error_logfile = -

# Expose the configuration file in the web server
expose_config = False

# Set to true to turn on authentication:
# http://pythonhosted.org/airflow/security.html#web-authentication
authenticate = False

# Filter the list of dags by owner name (requires authentication to be enabled)
filter_by_owner = False

# Filtering mode. Choices include user (default) and ldapgroup.
# Ldap group filtering requires using the ldap backend
#
# Note that the ldap server needs the "memberOf" overlay to be set up
# in order to user the ldapgroup mode.
owner_mode = user

# Default DAG view.  Valid values are:
# tree, graph, duration, gantt, landing_times
dag_default_view = tree

# Default DAG orientation. Valid values are:
# LR (Left->Right), TB (Top->Bottom), RL (Right->Left), BT (Bottom->Top)
dag_orientation = LR

# Puts the webserver in demonstration mode; blurs the names of Operators for
# privacy.
demo_mode = False

# The amount of time (in secs) webserver will wait for initial handshake
# while fetching logs from other worker machine
log_fetch_timeout_sec = 5

# By default, the webserver shows paused DAGs. Flip this to hide paused
# DAGs by default
hide_paused_dags_by_default = False

# Consistent page size across all listing views in the UI
page_size = 100

[email]
email_backend = airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp


[smtp]
# If you want airflow to send emails on retries, failure, and you want to use
# the airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp function, you have to configure an
# smtp server here
smtp_host = localhost
smtp_starttls = True
smtp_ssl = False
# Uncomment and set the user/pass settings if you want to use SMTP AUTH
# smtp_user = airflow
# smtp_password = airflow
smtp_port = 25
smtp_mail_from = airflow@example.com


[celery]
# This section only applies if you are using the CeleryExecutor in
# [core] section above

# The app name that will be used by celery
celery_app_name = airflow.executors.celery_executor

# The concurrency that will be used when starting workers with the
# "airflow worker" command. This defines the number of task instances that
# a worker will take, so size up your workers based on the resources on
# your worker box and the nature of your tasks
celeryd_concurrency = 16

# When you start an airflow worker, airflow starts a tiny web server
# subprocess to serve the workers local log files to the airflow main
# web server, who then builds pages and sends them to users. This defines
# the port on which the logs are served. It needs to be unused, and open
# visible from the main web server to connect into the workers.
worker_log_server_port = 8793

# The Celery broker URL. Celery supports RabbitMQ, Redis and experimentally
# a sqlalchemy database. Refer to the Celery documentation for more
# information.
#broker_url = sqla+mysql://airflow:airflow@localhost:3306/airflow
broker_url = sqs://

# Another key Celery setting
#celery_result_backend = db+mysql://airflow:airflow@localhost:3306/airflow
celery_result_backend = db+psycopg2://postgres:$password@localhost/datalake_airflow_cluster_v1_master1_database_1

# Celery Flower is a sweet UI for Celery. Airflow has a shortcut to start
# it `airflow flower`. This defines the IP that Celery Flower runs on
flower_host = 0.0.0.0

# This defines the port that Celery Flower runs on
flower_port = 5555

# Default queue that tasks get assigned to and that worker listen on.
default_queue = default

# Import path for celery configuration options
celery_config_options = airflow.config_templates.default_celery.DEFAULT_CELERY_CONFIG

[dask]
# This section only applies if you are using the DaskExecutor in
# [core] section above

# The IP address and port of the Dask cluster's scheduler.
cluster_address = 127.0.0.1:8786


[scheduler]
# Task instances listen for external kill signal (when you clear tasks
# from the CLI or the UI), this defines the frequency at which they should
# listen (in seconds).
job_heartbeat_sec = 5

# The scheduler constantly tries to trigger new tasks (look at the
# scheduler section in the docs for more information). This defines
# how often the scheduler should run (in seconds).
scheduler_heartbeat_sec = 5

# after how much time should the scheduler terminate in seconds
# -1 indicates to run continuously (see also num_runs)
run_duration = -1

# after how much time a new DAGs should be picked up from the filesystem
min_file_process_interval = 0

dag_dir_list_interval = 300

# How often should stats be printed to the logs
print_stats_interval = 30

child_process_log_directory = /home/ec2-user/airflow/logs/scheduler

# Local task jobs periodically heartbeat to the DB. If the job has
# not heartbeat in this many seconds, the scheduler will mark the
# associated task instance as failed and will re-schedule the task.
scheduler_zombie_task_threshold = 300

# Turn off scheduler catchup by setting this to False.
# Default behavior is unchanged and
# Command Line Backfills still work, but the scheduler
# will not do scheduler catchup if this is False,
# however it can be set on a per DAG basis in the
# DAG definition (catchup)
catchup_by_default = True

# This changes the batch size of queries in the scheduling main loop.
# This depends on query length limits and how long you are willing to hold locks.
# 0 for no limit
max_tis_per_query = 0

# Statsd (https://github.com/etsy/statsd) integration settings
statsd_on = False
statsd_host = localhost
statsd_port = 8125
statsd_prefix = airflow

# The scheduler can run multiple threads in parallel to schedule dags.
# This defines how many threads will run.
max_threads = 2

authenticate = False

[ldap]
# set this to ldaps://<your.ldap.server>:<port>
uri = 
user_filter = objectClass=*
user_name_attr = uid
group_member_attr = memberOf
superuser_filter = 
data_profiler_filter = 
bind_user = cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com
bind_password = insecure
basedn = dc=example,dc=com
cacert = /etc/ca/ldap_ca.crt
search_scope = LEVEL

[mesos]
# Mesos master address which MesosExecutor will connect to.
master = localhost:5050

# The framework name which Airflow scheduler will register itself as on mesos
framework_name = Airflow

# Number of cpu cores required for running one task instance using
# 'airflow run <dag_id> <task_id> <execution_date> --local -p <pickle_id>'
# command on a mesos slave
task_cpu = 1

# Memory in MB required for running one task instance using
# 'airflow run <dag_id> <task_id> <execution_date> --local -p <pickle_id>'
# command on a mesos slave
task_memory = 256

# Enable framework checkpointing for mesos
# See http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/slave-recovery/
checkpoint = False

# Failover timeout in milliseconds.
# When checkpointing is enabled and this option is set, Mesos waits
# until the configured timeout for
# the MesosExecutor framework to re-register after a failover. Mesos
# shuts down running tasks if the
# MesosExecutor framework fails to re-register within this timeframe.
# failover_timeout = 604800

# Enable framework authentication for mesos
# See http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/configuration/
authenticate = False

# Mesos credentials, if authentication is enabled
# default_principal = admin
# default_secret = admin


[kerberos]
ccache = /tmp/airflow_krb5_ccache
# gets augmented with fqdn
principal = airflow
reinit_frequency = 3600
kinit_path = kinit
keytab = airflow.keytab


[github_enterprise]
api_rev = v3


[admin]
# UI to hide sensitive variable fields when set to True
hide_sensitive_variable_fields = True
```

I'm not too sure what's going on here. Is there additional setup I need to do on Celery or anything else? I'm also confused as to how it knows which SQS queue to use on AWS? Does it create a new queue itself or do I need to create the queue on AWS and put that url somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39967889/5191221

Taken from there:

So replace:

```
celery_result_backend = postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@192.168.1.2:5432/airflow
```

with something like:

```
celery_result_backend = db+postgresql://username:password@192.168.1.2:5432/airflow
```