# sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:None

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to run a Python-Flask project. I have all the requirements installed. But still, whenever I try to run the server I get an error saying

`sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:driver`

Can anyone please tell me what can be wrong here and which file I need to examine?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some relevant code, so it's easier for others to help with your problem. Also have you looked at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/15648814/9098350?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on Heroku using Heroku Postgres plug-in.
After two days headache the bellow solutions works me.

`DATABASE_URL = os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL").replace("postgres", "postgresql")`